# Install libusb 1.0.9 on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I am not sure how to install libusb 1.0.9 on Arch Linux. pacman does not offer it and the package seems to have been deleted from the repository. I tried compiling from source but it does not seem to be picked up correctly.

Comment: Is there some reason you need 1.0.9 instead of [the current version](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/libusb/)?

Comment: Libusb has been replaced by libusbx as beeing out of date.

Comment: https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb/issues/34

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a package that no longer exists.

Arch doesn't work like that: it is a rolling release so, as newer packages are pushed to the mirrors (on a daily basis), the older ones are removed: attempting to download one will typically throw a 404 error.

If you must build a package from source (to make customizations, for example); make sure your machine is fully up-to-date (`pacman -Syyu`) and use either a PKGBUILD from [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Abs) or, if the package is not in Arch's official repositiories, [the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR).

This way you can be sure<sup>1</sup> that you will be building a package with the correct dependency versions and `pacman` will manage the final installation (and eventual removal, if you decide to do that).

You should only really use the traditional compilation method and bypass `pacman` if you really are confident you know exactly what you are doing.

<sup>1. Assuming, of course, the AUR packager knows what they are doing; it is, after all, an unsupported repsitory so use with caution.</sup>

Comment: Right. I'm not used to arch. I'm used to installing rpms on CentOs and then installing what I need using yum